# What's wrong with time subtraction?

Tags: java, date, time

I know that `Date` class can be really painful at times.

Could you please give me some painkillers in the form of the piece of advice on how to subtract time?

What I have is:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String s = "13.04.2015 16:00";
String s2 = "13.04.2015 15:30";
Date date = format.parse(s);
System.out.println(timeFormat.format(date.getTime() - format.parse(s2).getTime()));
```

This gives me 02:30:00, but I'd love to get 00:30:00 :)

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: always specify `Locale` in `SimpleDateFormat`. This will protect you from many bugs. BTW, 00:30 UTC is 02:30 Kiyv (I suppose it's your location timezone), so your code works pretty well.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Oh, now I see. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to force common `TimeZone` for both `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

before formatting `date`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you are stuck to Java Date class by some requirements, but if you are working with date and time a lot in your application I recommend [Joda-Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). It solves many problems out of the box and allows executing operations on date and time in easier way.

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely look at it!